# Stable convergence in distribution

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Consider the following definition.

**Definition**

*Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables defined on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$
with value in $\mathbb{R}^N$. We say that the sequence $X_n$ converges stably in distribution
with limit $X$, written $X_n\stackrel{\text{st}}{\longrightarrow} X$, if and only
if,  for any bounded continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R}$ and for any $\mathcal{F}$-measurable random variable $Z$, it happens that:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{E}[f(X_n)\,Z]=\mathbb{E}[f(X)\,Z].
$$*

I want to prove that if
$$
Y_n\stackrel{\text{st}}{\longrightarrow} Y
$$
then
$$
(Y_n,Z)\stackrel{\text{d}}{\longrightarrow}(Y,Z),
$$
for any measurable $Z$ and where $\stackrel{\text{d}}{\longrightarrow}$ indicates the standard convergence in distribution.

My idea is to use the Portmanteau Lemma, so I want to prove that, for any continuous bounded function $g$ it holds that 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{E}[g(Y_n,Z)]=\mathbb{E}[g(Y,Z)].\quad (1)
$$
Since $Y_n\stackrel{\text{st}}{\longrightarrow} X$ I know that for any continuous bounded function $f$ it holds that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{E}[f(Y_n)\,Z]=\mathbb{E}[f(Y)\,Z],\quad (2),
$$
however I do not know how to pass from (2) to (1).

===================================================

As suggested below I tried with Levy continuity theorem, but I am not sure that it is ok to consider a complex $f$. This is my poof:

[image]

Comment: Probably I have found a solution, quite simple indeed. For every $g(x,z)$ bounded and continuous define
$$f(x) = g(x,z)/z$$
which is bounded and continuous in $x$.

Comment: From my point of view, it would be easier to use Lévys continuity theorem, i.e. the fact that convergence in distribution is equivalent to convergence of the characteristic functions.

Comment: @saz would this require the adoption of a complex $f$ ?

Comment: Yes, but for this you can write $f = \text{Re} \, f+ i \, \text{Im f}$ and use the linearity of the expectation