# When convergence in distribution implies stable convergence

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

In a previous [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2733855/stable-convergence-in-distribution) I asked help to clarify a property of stable convergence in distribution:

**Definition**

*Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables defined on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$
with value in $\mathbb{R}^N$. We say that the sequence $X_n$ converges stably in distribution
with limit $X$, written $X_n\stackrel{\text{st}}{\longrightarrow} X$, if and only
if,  for any bounded continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R}$ and for any $\mathcal{F}$-measurable bounded random variable $W$, it happens that:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{E}[f(X_n)\,W]=\mathbb{E}[f(X)\,W].
$$*

What I need to prove now is the following:

Assume
$$
(Y_n,Z)\stackrel{\text{d}}{\longrightarrow}(Y,Z),
$$

for all measurable random variable $Z$, then

$$
(Y_n,Z)\stackrel{\text{st}}{\longrightarrow}(Y,Z)
$$
for all measurable random variables $Z$. So I need to prove that, for any bounded continuous function $f$ and for any measurable $Z$ it holds that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{E}[f(Y_n,Z)\,W]=\mathbb{E}[f(Y,Z)\,W]
$$
for all bounded random variables $W$.

I tried unsuccessfully with Portmanteau and Levy continuity theorem…

=================================================================

In practice I am trying to prove this proposition from the paper by [Podolskij and Vetter](http://www.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/imperia/md/content/mathematik3/publications/stableclt510.pdf):

[image]

I did this reasoning for (1)=>(3), but I am not so sure of its correctness.

[image]

Comment: You will certainly need some assumption on the integrability of $W$; if $W$ is not integrable, then the expectations are not even well-defined. It seems to me that the paper assumes that $W$ is bounded (in the sense that $\|W\|_{L^{\infty}} < \infty$), and this simplifies the proof a lot.

Comment: How did you face the problem with the Portmanteau? The idea can be to take as particular $Z$ the $W$, but probably you will need some additional assumptions about $W$ as noticed by @saz.

Comment: Yes, sorry, the $W$ must be bounded.

Comment: In line with the saz comment, let $X$ be any random variable with finite mean but infinite variance, and define $X_n = X/n$.  Then $X_n\rightarrow 0$ in distribution but $E[X_nX] = \infty$ for all $n$.

Comment: @AlmostSureUser Does $\mathbb R^N$ mean $N$-dimensional real space or $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$?

Comment: @AlexFrancisco It means the $N$-dimensional real space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\dto{\xrightarrow{\mathrm{d}}}\def\stto{\xrightarrow{\mathrm{st}}}\def\mto{\xrightarrow{\mathrm{m}}}$$(3) \Rightarrow (2)$: Trivial.

$(2) \Rightarrow (1)$: For any $g \in C_b(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and bounded $\mathscr{F}$-measurable $W$, suppose $|W| \leqslant M$. Take\begin{align*}
f: \mathbb{R}^N × \mathbb{R} &\longrightarrow \mathbb{R},\\
(y, z) &\longmapsto g(y) · \frac{1}{2} (|z + M| - |z - M|).
\end{align*}
Because $(Y_n, W) \dto (Y, W)$ and $f \in C_b(\mathbb{R}^{N + 1})$, then$$
E(g(Y_n) W) = E(f(Y_n, W)) \to E(f(Y, W)) = E(g(Y) W). \quad n \to \infty
$$
Therefore, $Y_n \stto Y$.

$(1) \Rightarrow (3)$: Suppose $Z$ and $W$ are $\mathscr{F}$-measurable and $W$ is bounded. First, for any $A \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and $B \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$, there exists $\{g_k\} \subseteq C_b(\mathbb{R}^N)$ such that $g_k \mto I_A$, i.e.$$
m(\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^N \mid g_k(x) \neq I_A(x)\}) \to 0. \quad k \to \infty
$$
For any $k \geqslant 1$, because $Y_n \stto Y$ and $I_B(Z) W$ is $\mathscr{F}$-measurable and bounded, then$$
E(g_k(Y_n) I_B(Z) W) \to E(g_k(Y) I_B(Z) W). \quad n \to \infty
$$
Note that $g_k \mto I_A$ and $I_B(Z) W$ is bounded, thus$$
E(I_A(Y_n) I_B(Z) W) \to E(I_A(Y) I_B(Z) W). \quad n \to \infty \tag{1}
$$

Now, for any $C \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^{N + 1})$, there exists $\{A_{k, j}\} \subseteq \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and $\{B_{k, j}\} \subseteq \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\{h_k\}$ defined by\begin{align*}
h_k : \mathbb{R}^N × \mathbb{R} &\longrightarrow \mathbb{R},\\
(y, z) &\longmapsto \sum_{j = 1}^{s_k} I_{A_{k, j}}(y) I_{B_{j, k}}(z)
\end{align*}
satisfies $h_k \mto I_C$. For any $k \geqslant 1$, from (1) there is$$
E(h_k(Y_n, Z) W) \to E(h_k(Y, Z) W). \quad n \to \infty
$$
Because $h_k \mto I_C$ and $W$ is bounded, then$$
E(I_C(Y_n, Z) W) \to E(I_C(Y, Z) W). \quad n \to \infty \tag{2}
$$

Now, for any $f \in C_b(\mathbb{R}^{N + 1})$, there exists a sequence of simple functions $\{f_k\}$ such that $f_k \rightrightarrows f$. For any $k \geqslant 1$, from (2) there is$$
E(f_k(Y_n, Z) W) \to E(f_k(Y, Z) W). \quad n \to \infty
$$
Because $f_k \rightrightarrows f$ and $W$ is bounded, then$$
E(f(Y_n, Z) W) \to E(f(Y, Z) W). \quad n \to \infty
$$
Therefore, $(Y_n, Z) \stto (Y, Z)$.

Comment: The proof of $(1)\Rightarrow (3)$ I had in mid was much simpler:

Assume 
$$Y_n\stackrel{st}{\rightarrow} Y.$$
Then, by definition,  
$$
E[g(Y_n)\,W]\to E[g(Y)\,W]
$$ 
for any bounded continuous function $g(y)$ and for any bounded random variable $W$. Now consider any  bounded continuous function $f(y,z)$, an  arbitrary $\mathcal{F}$-measurable variable $Z$ and note that
$$E[f(Y_n,Z)\,W]=E[E[f(Y_n,c)\,W | Z=c]]\rightarrow E[E[f(Y,c)\,W | Z=c]]= E[f(Y,Z)\,W].$$

Comment: @AlmostSureUser This works only when $Z$ is a continuous or discrete random variable. For $Z$ in general, the conditinal expectation is hard to rigorously characterize.

Comment: I do not understand the meaning of the double arrow.

Comment: @AlmostSureUser It means uniform convergence.

Comment: ok, thank you. Another clarification: I do not see how we pass form the penultimate to the last one. Do we take $k\rightarrow\infty$ ? Is it legitimate?

Comment: @AlmostSureUser Suppose $M_k=\|f_k-f\|$ and $|W|\leqslant M$. Because\begin{align*}|E(f(Y_n, Z) W)-E(f(Y, Z) W)|&\leqslant|E(f(Y_n, Z) W)-E(f_k(Y_n, Z) W)|\\&\quad+|E(f_k(Y_n, Z) W)-E(f_k(Y, Z) W)|\\&\quad+|E(f_k(Y, Z) W)-E(f(Y, Z) W)|\\&\leqslant M_kM+|E(f_k(Y_n, Z) W)-E(f_k(Y, Z) W)|+M_kM,\end{align*}and $M_k→0$ ($k→∞$), so$$\varlimsup_{n→∞}|E(f(Y_n, Z) W)-E(f(Y, Z) W)|\leqslant2M_kM,$$and make $k→∞$ to get $E(f(Y_n, Z) W)→E(f(Y, Z) W)$.

Comment: @Saad I gather that the existence of a sequence $(g_k)$ is given by Lusin's Theorem. What do you mean by convergence in "m"? I am not exactly sure why the step from the equation before (1) to (1) holds. Could you please elaborate? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What I suggested in the comment was the following idea: by Portmanteau
$$
(Y_n,Z)\stackrel{\text{d}}{\longrightarrow}(Y,Z),
$$
IFF
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{E}[f(X_n, \, Z)]=\mathbb{E}[f(X,\,Z)]
$$
for any measurable bounded continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^{N+1}\to\mathbb{R}$.

Then take as particular $Z := W$. Then you should have that 
$$
(Y_n)\stackrel{\text{st}}{\longrightarrow}(Y).
$$
since you can seen $f(Y_n,W)\,W$ for any $f$ C.B. as a particular $f_1(Y_n,W)$ C.B. under the assumption on $W$.

Moreover $$
(Y_n,Z)\stackrel{\text{st}}{\longrightarrow}(Y,Z).
$$
should follow from
$$
(Y_n)\stackrel{\text{st}}{\longrightarrow}(Y).
$$
applying bounded convergence theorem.

Is it right?

Comment: why  bounded convergence? It requires point wise convergence:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235511/explanation-of-the-bounded-convergence-theorem

Comment: @AlmostSureUser You are right, I was too sloppy: bounded convergence is not immediate. Your argument seems right to me. Anyway, you can also prove it, as in proposition 2.5 (i) of  Podolskij and Vetter paper, taking the sequence $V_n$ that converges in probability to $V$ constant and equal to $Z$.